# Php loop for displaying content

Tags: php, wordpress, css

I've start meaking my own wordpress template, in first step I made sketch in HTML. It's look like this.

[image: Sketch]

I was thinking about that, black rectangle is "Post Image", and I want 4 in one line. That I should solve with for loop, in while loop(I guess). 
In my opinion it should look like this (It's loop from twenty eleven theme)

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

        <div id="primary">
            <div id="content" role="main">

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php for(i=0;i<8;i++)?>
                    {<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>}
                    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            </div>
        </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But I have problem, how I should solve problem with positioning. I guess it should be one class post. Below I give you my codes. Please help.

My html code:

```
<div class="postbar">
    <div class="post1">
        <a href="index.html">
        <div id="postOver"></div>
        </a>
        <div id="postText">text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="post2">
        <a href="index.html">
        <div id="postOver"></div>
        </a>
        <div id="postText">text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="post3">
        <a href="index.html">
        <div id="postOver"></div>
        </a>
        <div id="postText">text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="post4">
        <a href="index.html">
        <div id="postOver"></div>
        </a>
        <div id="postText">text</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="postbar">
    <div class="post1">
        <a href="index.html">
        <div id="postOver"></div>
        </a>
        <div id="postText">text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="post2">
        <a href="index.html">
        <div id="postOver"></div>
        </a>
        <div id="postText">text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="post3">
        <a href="index.html">
        <div id="postOver"></div>
        </a>
        <div id="postText">text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="post4">
        <a href="index.html">
        <div id="postOver"></div>
        </a>
        <div id="postText">text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS code:

```
  div.postbar{
        position:relative; left:255px; 
        height:222px;
        }
    div.post1 {
        margin-top:17px;
        position:relative; 
        margin-left:1%;
        padding-left:3px;
        padding-right:3px;
        width:222px;
        height:222px;
        }
    div.post2 {
        position:absolute;  top:-1px; left:260px;
        margin-left:1%;
        width:222px;
        height:222px;
        }
    div.post3 {
        position:relative;  top:-222px; left:520px;
        margin-left:1%;
        padding-left:3px;
        padding-right:3px;
        width:222px;
        height:222px;
        }
    div.post4 {
        position:relative;  top:-444px; left:780px; 
        margin-left:1%;
        padding-left:3px;
        padding-right:3px;
        width:222px;
        height:222px;
        }
    div.postNext {

        position:absolute; left:250px; top:-1px; 
        margin-left:1%;
        padding-left:3px;
        padding-right:3px;
        width:222px;
        height:222px;

        }

    #postOver{
        width:222px;
        height:222px;
        background-image:url(img/arch.jpg);
        box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #000000;
        -webkit-transition:width 1s;
        }
    *:hover > #postOver{
        width: 0;
    }
    #postText{
        position:relative; top:-222px;
        font-size:12px;
        width:222px;
        height:222px;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #000000;
        color:black;
        text-align:center;
        z-index:-1;
        }
```

Comment: You're going to want to make a custom template and use that for display. http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Examples_of_Pages_and_Templates

Comment: it looks like you are using a CMS .. without seeing the actual page that builds the content it'll be hard to tweak it. Are you using joomla / Wordpress / etc? some modules can get pretty hairy.

Comment: @Silvertiger I'm using wordpress

Comment: It's more likely to get an answer [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MetalFrog Ok but what about positioning new post? How I should do it? There is someting linke reference to last located post?

Comment: When you say "4 in one line" do you mean a *COLUMN* (vertical) or *ROW* (horizontal)? Do you want to have a fixed number of posts on only one page, or are you going to be paging (page 1, page 2) through the posts and are going to have say, 10 posts on each page?

The first thing about your code is that you're declaring the same width and height on each class. You should make *ONE* class and re-use it with the width, height, and margin. 

Also, using left positioning and margin left is going to complicate things for you.

Comment: @j-man86 I mean ROW. I was thinking about paging. So I should use height:inherit beside height:222px? About margin and left, ok I will repair it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Mr.TAMER said, would be better to search for an Answer in [WordPress Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Here is code that could be a possible solution for your problem:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .post { float:left; display:block; width:222px; height:222px; margin: 0 3px; }
    .post.first { margin-left:0px; }
    .post.last { margin-right:0px; }

    /* Clear fix from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ */
    .clearfix:after { visibility: hidden;display: block;font-size: 0;content: " ";clear: both;height: 0; }
    * html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
    *:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */ 
</style>

<?php
    $args = array( //Query variables take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args ); // Doing the Query

    if( $query->have_posts() ) { // Checking if there is any posts with the arguments above

        while( $query->have_posts() ) { // Looping throught the selected posts
            $query->the_post(); // Selecting the next as the actual Post
            ?>
            <div class="post<?php echo ( $current_post == 0 ? " first" : ( $current_post == $post_count ? " last" : "" ) ); ?>">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <div id="postOver"></div>
                </a>
                <div id="postText">text</div>
            </div>
            <?php
            if( $current_post == $post_count )
                echo "<div class=\"clearfix\"></div>";
        }
    } else { // If there isn't any posts with the Arguments set above


    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); // Reseting the Post data so you can re-use the loop
```

Comment: I go to Wordpress Exchange and they told me that I should go here. soo